# new line not registered in docx.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx

I am using the docxjs library. I am trying to add line breaks into the doc im generating but I'm unsure of how to do this. `\n` character gets ignored. How can i add line breaks to my doc?

The paragraph I want to add line breaks to:

```
new Paragraph( {
        text: '\n',
        children: [
          ...Object.entries( dataItem ).map( ([fieldName, fieldValue]) => new Paragraph( {
            text: fieldName,
            children: Object.entries( fieldValue ).map( ([dataSource, dataValue]) => new Paragraph( {
              text: dataSource,
              children: Object.values( dataValue ).map( value => new Paragraph(value) )
            }) )
          }) ),
          new Paragraph( {text: '_', children: [new PageBreak()]} )
        ]
      } )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that paragraph is equal newline in text. Isn't it?

```
doc.addSection({
    properties: {},
    children: [
        new Paragraph({
            children: [
                new TextRun("First line"),
            ],
        }),
        new Paragraph({
          children: [],  // Just newline without text
        }),
        new Paragraph({
            children: [
                new TextRun("Second line"),
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: It does create a new line but it also requires text so I can't use it if i just want a new line

Comment: you can use without text         new Paragraph({
            children: [
            ],
        }),
I edited example above

Comment: Thanks for that, however isnt that a hack? Shouldn't there be a simple way to insert a line break?

Comment: I think it isn't because structure of Word document use this way too.

Answer (score 2):

The docxjs library has built-in feature for line break [here](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/text?id=break). First, we need to split our lines and then we can use `break` property on the `TextRun` object:

```
const lines = "This sentence\n is breaked\n into three lines"
const textRuns = lines.split("\n").map(line=>new TextRun({break:1,text:line}))
const paragraph = new Paragraph({children: textRuns})
```

Answer (score 2):

This function help you to keep new lines and download your docx file with blob.

Pass your text to **generateDoc** function as showing below

as **ExampleText** variable hold example text with new linese.
pass it **generateDoc(ExampleText)** function
creat a object with split function and hold in **textString** variable and add to **docx.Paragraph** this can make new paragraph on eache line.

```
const ExampleText = "This sentence\n is breaked\n into three lines \n Faizan bhai"
generateDoc(ExampleText);

function generateDoc(text) {
    const textString = text.split("\n").map(line=>new docx.TextRun({break:1,text:line}))
    const doc = new docx.Document({
        sections: [{
            properties: {},
            children: [
                new docx.Paragraph({children: textString})
            ],
        }]
    });
    docx.Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        downloadBlob(blob, "example.docx");
    });
}
function downloadBlob(blob, name = 'file.docx') {
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = blobUrl;
    link.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('click', { 
        bubbles: true, 
        cancelable: true, 
        view: window 
        })
    );
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

if youw want to download docx file call **downloadBlob** function with 2 parameters first is docx blob and second is optional is file name (Default file name is file.docx)

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggeston i have updated the description.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but the accepted answer does not allow you to dynamically add line breaks and I could not get Haris Wirabrata's to work although it did help me. My solution splits text by a marker (in this case 'break') into an array and then loops through the array to add textRun elements to a paragraph element. Note the extra textRun with the break parameter [see docs here](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/text?id=break). Example code below.

```
    function getTextPara(textElement) {

    var docx = require("docx");
    var fs = require('fs');
    var text;
    var para = new docx.Paragraph({
        children: [
        ]
    });

    
    var cleanTextArray = testElement.split("<break>");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < cleanTextArray.length; i++) {

       text = new docx.TextRun({
            text: cleanTextArray[i],
        });

        para.addChildElement(text);

        text = new docx.TextRun({
            text: "",
            break: 1,
        });

        para.addChildElement(text);
    }

    return para;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const paragraphs = yourText.split("\n")
    .map(line => new docx.Paragraph({
      children: [new docx.TextRun({ text: line, size: 24, font: 'Arial' })]
    }));

  const doc = new docx.Document();
  doc.addSection({
    properties: {},
    children: paragraphs
  });
```

Comment: Its always better to add some understanding details and explanation, it helps to understand how solution works. As its not single place to use maybe in various way we can use specific solution. Please add additional description and supporting details